# how to remove the whitespace below the bootstrap progress bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar, removing-whitespace

How can I remove or minimize the gap in between progress bar and string:

```
<div class='progress'><div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='60' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 80%;'></div></div>
<!--Here will be a huge whitespace, and needs to be removed-->
remove white space above this line
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ts9b5m4/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you think we've enough information to help you ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Totally.

Comment: @PedroLobito Explain why there is not enough info, OP added html and default bootstrap has the css, what else is needed?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith the user posted a link to an actual example after my question - http://jsfiddle.net/1ts9b5m4 . It's better now, but the example should be posted on SO and not on an external website.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `style="margin-bottom:0px;"`

```
<div class='progress' style="margin-bottom:0px;"><div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='60' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 80%;'></div></div>
<!--Here will be a huge whitespace, and needs to be removed-->
remove white space above this line
```

Comment: thank you, this works. I am open for any other elegant or bootstrap solutions. Thanks!

Comment: @xam the bootstrap "progress" has a default margin of 20px, how else would you want it done?

Comment: Your only other option would be to put it in the css see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1ts9b5m4/2/

Comment: I've looked around on http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and it doesn't let you change the margin-bottom there.  There is another option.  If you're hosting the bootstrap css yourself, and not relying on a CDN, you could make the change there.  There is a `.progress{ margin-bottom:20px; ... };`  Just remove the `margin-bottom:20px;`

Answer (score 0):

Margin alone didn't work for me. I had to override both margin-bottom **and** height CSS attributes for the progress bar. I placed this into a small blade file and used `@include` to place it in the content section of forms that used progress bar.

In a file views/splitpieces/overridecss.blade.php:

```
<style>
.progress-bar{ 
    margin-bottom:0px;
    height:1%;
}
</style>
```

In the form using progress bar:

```
@include('splitpieces.cssoverride')
```

For me this had to be inside the `@section('content')` to work, otherwise the bootstrap CDN trumped the style modifier.

Hope this helps.